# Why Callback of typeset() Javascript function is executed after program is terminated?

Tags: node.js, callback, mathjax

When I execute following `JavaScript` program on `Node.js`

```js
var mjAPI = require('mathjax-node');
mjAPI.config({
  MathJax: {
    // traditional MathJax configuration
  }
});
mjAPI.start();

writeLatexInfo("1","\\alpha");
writeLatexInfo("2","\\omega");

console.log(">> TERMINATED");

function writeLatexInfo(sRef, sLatex)
  {
  console.log(`<ref>${sRef}</ref><latex>${sLatex}</latex>`);

  mjAPI.typeset({
    math: sLatex,
    format: "TeX", // or "inline-TeX", "MathML"
    mml:true,      // or svg:true, or html:true
    }, function (data) { if (!data.errors) { console.log(data.mml); }
  });
 
  }
```

I obtain following result where `>> TERMINATED` is displayed before `<math>` element

```
<ref>1</ref><latex>\alpha</latex>
<ref>2</ref><latex>\omega</latex>
>> TERMINATED
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="\alpha">
  <mi>&#x03B1;<!-- α --></mi>
</math>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="\omega">
  <mi>&#x03C9;<!-- ω --></mi>
</math>
```

What must I do, to obtain following display ?

```
<ref>1</ref><latex>\alpha</latex>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="\alpha">
  <mi>&#x03B1;<!-- α --></mi>
</math>
<ref>2</ref><latex>\omega</latex>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" alttext="\omega">
  <mi>&#x03C9;<!-- ω --></mi>
</math>
>> TERMINATED
```

where each `<math>` element follow respective `</latex>` end tag.

What can I do so that `callback` function defined in `mjAPI.typeset` is executed synchronously with rest of program ?

Comment: No, it's not executed after the program terminated, but your `console.log()` happens way before your program terminates, because `mjAPI.typeset` probably is asynchonous ...

Comment: If you want your `TERMINATED` output only after your typesetting finished, you have to execute it from the callback